# Force html5 appcache to load on bad connection

Tags: connection, offline, html5-appcache

I created a webapp with offline application cache which is working fine in flight mode, but when i'm on a bad connection it keeps on trying to load the normal site because the connection is not totally dead.

Is it possible to force a webapp to use the appcache (fallback) on a bad connection for example by using the navigator.connection property?

tx!

Comment: How about a short timeout on Server?